# Pick $1$ Number ($A$) in $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and $1$ Number ($B$) in $\{1,2,\ldots,n\} - \{A\}$. What is the sample space and probability function?

Tags: probability, statistics

So we pick the number A from {1,2,...,n} (uniformly at random).

We pick the number B from {1,2,...,n} - {A} (uniformly at random).

What is the sample space and probability function? Below are my ideas, I am slightly confused because of the - {A} when picking the number B.

Here is my attempt:

The sample space is:

$$\Omega = \{\langle A, B\rangle \mid A \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}, B \in \{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}\}$$

For the probability function, we have n ways to pick A, so the probability is $1/n$

For B, the probability of any number being chosen from 1 to n is $1/n$, however, we have to subtract whatever value we got from A, so the values we can choose from are $1/(n-1)$. Giving us the probability function:
$$(1/n)(1/(n-1))$$

Is this correct? Or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to subtract $A$ from $n$; they're two different animals. Imagine, for example, that $A \in \{\textrm{red, green, blue}\}$. What would $n-A$ mean? Instead, $n-1$, since you've removed one option.

Comment: @Théophile So instead of $n-A$, we would have $n-1$ because we remove an option from the set? I guess that was my confusion because I assumed we were just subtracting whatever value A was from whatever value we chose for B.

Comment: Part of the confusion might be from the notation for "minus". There's normal arithmetic subtraction, like $n-1$, but there's also "set subtraction", as in $\{1,2,\ldots,n\} - \{A\}$. Another symbol for this is $\setminus$ (typeset like so: `\setminus`), which serves as a reminder that there's something different happening: $\{1,2,\ldots,n\} \setminus \{A\}$.

Comment: @Théophile Ahhh yea that makes sense. I updated the question with the actual notation used in the book I am working out of. Sorry about the confusion

Comment: I would assume that this is intended to be simply "selection without replacement."  That for instance, if $A$ were selected to be $5$ that $B$ would be selected uniformly from $\{1,2,3,4,6,7,\dots,n\}$.  In such a scenario, the sample space can be written in many ways such as $\Omega = \{(a,b)\in [n]^2~:~a\neq b\}$ where here $[n]$ is shorthand for the set $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$.  The probability of a specific $(a,b)$ (*with $a\neq b$*) being selected will be $\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$, equal to what you wrote.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for the response. I was curious as a follow up, what would be the probability of some specific number being chosen for A or B? For example, the number 3 (assuming n >= 3). So if A is 3, then B cannot choose 3. However, if A is not 3, then B can be 3. So A and B cannot both be three, so the probability of this event is the probability of A being 3 + probability of B being 3?

Comment: Yes, the probability of $A$ being a specific number in the range is $\frac{1}{n}$ and same too for the probability that $B$ is that number.  The probability at least one of them is that number is the sum of these i.e. $\frac{2}{n}$ since, as you noted, they are disjoint events.